# Does javac reorder actions?

Tags: java, javac

There are a lot of info about how HotSpot JIT C1/C2 reorders generated machine instructions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling). But I can't find any info about reordering of source code when using `javac`. Is this even a case?